# Do wystones actually affect Magala family monsters?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

I know that wystones help knock frenzied monsters out of frenzy, but as far as I can tell, the Magala (Gore, Chaotic, and Shagaru) family monsters spew frenzy inducing attacks throughout the entire battle whether they are in rage mode or not.  Maybe I'm missing a difference between frenzy and rage on these monsters, but it also seems like I can knock Gore out of his rage/frenzy without wystones.  Maybe I'm thinking that Gore's rage *is* his frenzy state when it isn't.

Additionally, even whenever I play with Gold Crown players, they don't seem to be using either of their wystones whenever we fight one of these monsters which makes me question further if wystones are good to use against them.  I also can't tell if **Brace** is giving me a defense boost against the attacks or not and I haven't noticed any excessive bouncing so I don't know if **Drive** is working either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do not. Wystones only work on frenzied and apex monsters, there is no effect when using wystones on the Magala family.

[source](http://monsterhunter.wikia.com/wiki/MH4U:_Wyceum)

"Wystones are items used on your weapon to quell the Frenzy in monsters."

Answer (score 1):

No, wystones have no effect on any of the monsters from the Magala family. While they are responsible for the frenzy, they are not affected by it themselves.

Only monsters with the "Frenzied" or "Apex" labels at the bottom of their icon (on the target cam panel) are affected by wystones.

(Source: personal experience, gold crown, and 300+ hours logged)